# How can we interact with a google carboard video?

Tags: android, google-cardboard, google-vr

I want to play a 360 degree video using the google-vr sdk and the VrVideoView on Android. Is there any way to use the reticle (google gaze) to point at a certain point? Can we play stereoscopic 360 degree video in an OpenGL window? The sdk demo apps have these two functions in two separate apps.

In short, can we use the reticle functionality without Unity or can we play 360 videos in Unity?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do both in Android but I only managed to get this working using canvas as a view and then placing this on top of the 360 video. Might not be the most ideal way but worked for me.

Is this what you're looking to do?

I'm trying to allow user to make selection from a list of videos by head tracking. If you have any ideas how to do this, let me know.

Comment: No not just to place the reticle. I need to interact with the video. Exactly like your scenario. For eg, I need to play a different video when a user looks at a certain point in the current video. Do you know if there's a way to get the head position when playing a VR video?

Comment: Ahh seems like we are on the same boat here. I believe you can use the "pitch" and "yaw". If you look at the isLookingAtObject() function and log out these variables while calling this function in onNewFrame(), it should give you the head co-ordinates

Comment: Hehe indeed. But the problem I'm having is that VrVideoView does not give us the head position and GvrView does not play videos.

Comment: I see. For my application, I don't need much "in-video" interaction so I'm using another library for the media player. Perhaps we can help each other out? Shoot us an email vincent@vincentloi.co.uk :)